# ggplot - reverse y axis when plotting geom_smooth with gamma error distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a `geom_smooth` using a gamma error distribution.

```r
library(ggplot)

data <- data.frame(x = 1:100, y = (1:100 + runif(1:100, min = 0, max = 50))^2)

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm', method.args = list(family = Gamma(link = "log")))
```

[image: geom smooth]

I also want to reverse the y-axis however using `scale_y_reverse`, but this causes the Gamma distribution to fail as it can't be applied to negative values. How can I reverse the y-axis for this plot?

```r
p + scale_y_reverse()
```

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
non-positive values not allowed for the 'Gamma' family
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are build-in methods to call out the predicted values of `geom_smooth` for `scale_y_reverse` to work.

Here's the more conventional method with visualizing of regression models, i.e. construct, predict and plot.

```
library(broom)
model <- glm(y ~ x, data, family = Gamma(link = "log"))
new <- augment(model, se=TRUE) 

ggplot(new, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y=exp(1)^.fitted)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=exp(1)^(.fitted + .se.fit)), linetype="dashed") + 
  geom_line(aes(y=exp(1)^(.fitted - .se.fit)), linetype="dashed") + 
  scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about `broom::augment`. That's really useful.

Comment: Works using `stats::predict` too, e.g. `cbind(data, data.frame(predict(model, se=TRUE)))`. But broom is a useful package on the whole to get acquainted with.